# Specify volume and other parameters for AWS EC2 AMI on instance start

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ami

I struggled to word this better but I want to be able to launch an EC2 instance using the Wordpress AMI by Bitnami.

I want to be able to do so using the aws-sdk for javascript, so that I can launch instances from my program.

The problem i face is that I cannot specify the size of the volume to be attached. Is there any way to do this? Perhaps create a custom AMI that is a modification of the existing one -- if so, how would i go about this?

I'm struggling with the AWS docs.

My instance call:

```
const startInstance = () => {
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const ec2 = new AWS.EC2({ apiVersion: '2016-11-15' });

    const instanceParams = {
        ImageId: 'ami-05d3ff95e7af0c839',
        InstanceType: 't2.micro',
        KeyName: 'filezilla2',
        MinCount: 1,
        MaxCount: 1
    };

    const instancePromise = new AWS.EC2({ apiVersion: '2016-11-15' }).runInstances(instanceParams).promise();

    instancePromise.then(
        function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            var instanceId = data.Instances[0].InstanceId;
            console.log("Created instance", instanceId);
            tagParams = {
                Resources: [instanceId], Tags: [
                    {
                        Key: 'Name',
                        Value: 'test from app'
                    }
                ]
            };

            var tagPromise = new AWS.EC2({ apiVersion: '2016-11-15' }).createTags(tagParams).promise();

            tagPromise.then(
                function (data) {
                    console.log("Instance tagged");
                    resolve(data);
                }).catch(
                    function (err) {
                        console.error(err, err.stack);
                        reject(err)
                    });
        }).catch(
            function (err) {
                console.error(err, err.stack);
                reject(err)
            });
});
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution, add this to your params object

```
BlockDeviceMappings: [
                {
                    DeviceName: '/dev/sda1',
                    Ebs: {
                        DeleteOnTermination: <<true || false>>,
                        VolumeSize: <<size in GB>>,
                        VolumeType: "gp2"
                    }
                }
            ],
```